# I get 404 error when I try endpoint on localhost

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I try GET on localhost:8080/path I get 404 error.

endpoint:

```
@Path("path")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Controller {
@GET
public String getString() {
return "hello";
}
}
```

project structure looks like this:

- com.example.demo.controller.Controller.java
- com.example.demo.DemoApplication.java

Project is generated with Spring Initializr with spring web and lombok and nothing else.

Comment: Did you register this endpoint? When you work with JAX-RS, you must register the endpoint. (I worked a long time ago, maybe there is another way now, but check for registering your endpoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JAX-RS with Spring Boot. You must use Spring MVC

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
public Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public String getString() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

You should start with reading the documentation:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-web-applications
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: I don't think so. He can do it using JAX-RS. https://dzone.com/articles/using-jax-rs-with-spring-boot-instead-of-mvc . I worked on a project that we used to use JAX-RS with Spring boot.

Comment: Yes sure he can but he said that he is using Spring Web and I showed the way who to do it with Spring web

Comment: Oh, I miss understanding. I'm sorry.